# Solving T(n) = 3T(n/3)+n/2 using master method

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I thought I understood the Master Method quite well till I saw this question

$T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{3})+\frac{n}{2}$

My approach:
  $a = 3 ; b=3$ and $f(n) = \frac{n}{2}$

$n^{\log_b{a}}$ = $n^{log_3{3}} = n$

This looked like a classic solution of master method using case 1.

But since case 1 implies $f(n) = n^{\log_3{3} - ε}$ and I cannot find any way that ε can be represented, I understand that case 1 is not the way.

However the solution says that this is solvable by case 2 of the master method and the solution is  $T(n) = \theta(n^{log_3{3}} \log^{ n}) $

Case 2 of the master method states that if $f(n) = n^{log_b{a}}  \log^{k}{ n}$ then $T(n) = \theta(n^{log_b{a}} \log^{k+1}{ n}) $

Can someone explain how this is solved using case 2 of the master method and why this fits under case 2?

Comment: Where did the $+e$ come from?  What's $e$?  I think you'll need to provide more context.  Please edit the question to show your work and where you got that expression.  Also, why do you think case 1 is appropriate? Please spell out your reasoning.  Give us something to work with; the more you can share your thinking, the more likely we can help you.

Comment: @D.W.  e stands for episilon. 
case 1 of the master method states that if $f(n) is O(n^{\log_b{a -ε}})$ where $a>0,b>1$ then $T(n) is   \theta (n^{\log_b{a}})$..

Updated the question to reflect the -ε instead of +ε

Comment: Note that you don't calculate the running time of the recurrence, whatever that would be. You attempt to *solve* the recurrence.

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers) explains the Master theorem at length. Duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recurrence of the form:

$$T(n)=aT(n/b)+O(n^d)$$

Case 2 of the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) applies when we do **equal work at every level** of the recursion tree. This happens when the amount of work done at the root - $O(n^d)$ - is equal to the amount of work done at the leaves. In other words, when the *rate of subproblem proliferation (RSP)* is equal to the *rate of work shrinkage (RWS)* per subproblem:

- The RSP is $a=3$ in your recurrence. This means that, as we move down the tree, we have more subproblems to solve (which is bad news). In particular, at level $j$, we have $3^j$ subproblems.
- The RWS is $b^d=3^1=3$ in your recurrence. This means that, as we move down the tree, each subproblem does less and less work (which is good news). In particular, at level $j$, each subproblem accounts for $O(n/3^j)$ of the total amount of work.

Since $a=b^d$, the RSP and the RWS cancel out. Thus, it is easy to predict what the running time will be. Since we have a logarithmic number of levels - $log(n)$ - and the total amount of work is the same at every level - $O(n)$ - then the running time is $O(n \cdot log(n))$.

Comment: @ Mario Cervera. Thanks. It makes perfect sense. I ran this through a recursion tree. At each level, the total work done was n/2. Therefore the total work done by the entire tree is the sum of work done at each level. i.e. $(n/2 + n/2 +. . .+n/2) \log{n}$ times.

Answer (score 1):

While applying master's theorem all you have to do is compare which of $f(n)$ or $(n^{\log_b{a}})$ is asymptotically greater. The greater of the two functions determines the solution to the recurrence. There are only possible outcomes for this comparison: 
[1] $(n^{\log_b{a}})$ is asymptotically greater than $f(n)$ 
[2] Both are asymptotically equal 
[3] $f(n)$ is asymptotically greater than $(n^{\log_b{a}})$

Yours falls in case 2.

Answer (score 1):

In the recurrence relation $T(n)=3T(\frac{n}{3})+\frac{n}{2}$

The last term $\frac{n}{2}$ can be written as $n\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ aka $n\cdot c$ cause $\frac{1}{2}$ is a constant.

From Masters Theorem:

$n^{\log_{3}(3)} =1$. So, $n^1= f(n)$

This resembles case 2 of masters theorem  $T(n) = \theta(n^{\log_{b}{a}}\log_{2}{n} )$

thus, $T(n) = \theta(n\log_{}{n} )$

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 of masters theorem says that:

**if** **`f(n) = θ(n^(logb a))`**, then **`T(n) = θ(n^(logb a)logn)`**.

`^` means power.

In term **`log n`** of **`θ(n^(logb a)logn)`**, the base does not matter.

So going by your way, you are right in saying that

**`a = 3; b = 3 and f(n) = n^2`**

```
f(n) = n/2

f(n) <= 2*(n/2) for all n > 1, this means that:

f(n) = O(n)
```

Also

```
f(n) >= 0.8*(n/2) for all n > 1, this means that:

f(n) = omega(n)
```

Hence **`f(n) = θ(n)`**

Therefore, the solution is **`T(n) = θ(nlogn)`**

Answer (score 0):

This question can be solved by Master Theorem:
In a recursion form :
[image]

where a>=1, b>1, k >=0 and p is a real number, then:

1. if a > b<sup>k</sup>, then
   [image: first case of master theorem]
2. if a = b<sup>k</sup>

   ```
      a.) if p >-1, then
   ```

[image: 2.a case of master theorem]

```
       b.) if p = -1, then
```

[image]

```
       c.) if p < -1, then
```

[image]
3. if a < b<sup>k</sup>
a.) if p >=0, then

[image]
b.) if p<0, then T(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup>)

So, the above equation

```
   T(n) = 3T(n/3) + n/3  

a = 3, b = 3, k =1, p =0
```

so it fall into 2.a case, where a = b<sup>k</sup>
So answer will be

```
O(n⋅log(n))
```